# MS Access: Two keys in a table, that every combination of them is unique

Tags: ms-access, key, unique

I have a table called orders.
It has a pimary key "Order_ID", and it has the fileds "Customer_ID" and "Product_ID".
How can I do that every combination of the Customer_ID and the Product_ID would be unique?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Make an unique index on Customer_ID + Product_ID.
To do that, open table in design view, create a unique index on customer_id, then open Indexes popup window and add the ProductId field to that index.
----edit:
At the end, the index list should show:

```
Primary Key    Order_id
MyIndex1       Customer_ID
               Product_ID
```

Comment: When I do that I can't save.
I get an errorbox that says double index name

Comment: Nevermind i didnt understand, I typed the index name twice. thank you it's working

Comment: Normal you cannot save if you have duplicates on the field set you want the be unique. You have to clean up your data first.